# Extracting RabbitMQ functionality to separate class

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I am going through the RabbitMQ tutorial ([this one](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html)) and have encountered a problem.

If I write the code as it is presented in the tutorial - it works fine. But I wanted to move the logic to separate class, so it looks better and is reusable.

```
public class Consumer
{
    private ConnectionFactory factory;
    private List<string> receivedData;

    public Consumer()
    {
        receivedData = new List<string>();
        factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };

        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            channel.QueueDeclare("hello", false, false, false, null);

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                receivedData.Add(message);
            };

            channel.BasicConsume("hello", true, consumer);
        }
    }

    public List<string> GetAllReceivedMessages()
    {
        return receivedData;
    }
}
```

Main program

```
var consumer = new Consumer();
while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            var messages = consumer.GetAllReceivedMessages();
            foreach (var msg in messages)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
```

I don't see any differences with the original. But all the time receivedData list is empty. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to put a breakpoint in the `Received` event handler? Does it get hit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `using` statements exit, the channel and connection are closed.